# Changed Blazor Value Not Updating in Browser

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Default Blazor (Server Side) template creates `Counter.razor` component.

```
<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

All good, however if I change it to update `currentCount` in the background like this for example:

```
@code {

    private int currentCount = 0;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
        {
            currentCount++;
        }

        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Current count is not updating in the browser, however if I click [Click me], it will show the current count.

Why does it require me to click or why would it not always show the current value?

Yes changing it to this works:

```
while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    currentCount++;
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

However, won't that re-render the whole component? Seems highly inefficient. Why don't I have to call `StateHasChanged` in the `OnClick` method also?

Comment: It works though, and this Q was about updating the value for demonstration purposes only, just to demonstrate the problem. Same behavior outside of OnInitializedAsync regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, won't that re-render the whole component?

Yes.  The Renderer updates it's copy of the UI, uses a diffing engine to detect changes but only "ships" changes to the browser UI.

> Seems highly inefficient.

It is a little, but you're using a single component and a one size fits all `ComponentBase`.

> Why don't I have to call StateHasChanged in the OnClick method also?

`ComponentBase` has a registered `IHandleEvent` that looks like this.  It calls  `StateHasChanged` either once or twice (depending on whether an async yield occurs) on all UI events (mouse clicks, focus, ....),

```cs
    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object? arg)
    {
        var task = callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
        var shouldAwaitTask = task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion &&
            task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled;

        // After each event, we synchronously re-render (unless !ShouldRender())
        // This just saves the developer the trouble of putting "StateHasChanged();"
        // at the end of every event callback.
        StateHasChanged();

        return shouldAwaitTask ?
            CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(task) :
            Task.CompletedTask;
    }

  private async Task CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch // avoiding exception filters for AOT runtime support
        {
            // Ignore exceptions from task cancellations, but don't bother issuing a state change.
            if (task.IsCanceled)
            {
                return;
            }

            throw;
        }

        StateHasChanged();
    }
```